# Can't boot into Ubuntu after installation of nVidia driver

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, 16.04, nvidia-prime

I run Ubuntu 16.04.

After reinstalling drivers for graphics card (nVidia prime) I got the following error while trying to boot:

```
Error: Driver 'ebridge' is already registered, aborting...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this problem as follows:

1. Menu GRUB2 - Advanced options for Ubuntu
2. Ubuntu with Linux **4.4.0-21-generic** (recovery mode) //kernel version is important!
3. When OS is booted, input the commands in terminal

   > ```
   > sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
   > sudo apt-get purge nvidia-settings
   > sudo apt-get purge nvidia-prime
   > ```
4. Reboot
5. Boot with new kernel version (4.4.0-23-generic)